# Can I make a three mySQL three fields from three databases interact together?

Tags: mysql

I need to have a mySQL database of inventory of a particular part number.

I have three databases:

1. Add inventory History
2. Remove Inventory History
3. Current Inventory

In each database, each has a number field.

Is it possible to create a formula so that "current" always has the latest number based on what is added and removed?

Can current have a formula to "add" and "subtract" from current number?

Instead of databases, should I create three different tables in "current"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a compelling reason to maintain the data in three databases, I would definitely consolidate them into one.

Assuming you don't want to handle this on the application layer, you can just add triggers on the 'add inventory' and 'remove inventory' history tables that would in turn either insert or update the relavent row in 'current inventory'.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html